# The method 'doc' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, to-json, fromjson

I am getting a few error in my project. Can you help me?

> The argument type 'StreamTransformer<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot*, List>'.

> The method 'doc' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'doc'.

> The getter 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Buy'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'fromJson', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'fromJson'.

The above error appears in the code below (1)

(1). firebase_api.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/ToDo/widget/Utils.dart';
import '../../Data/Model/BuyingListStore.dart';

class FirebaseApi {
  static Future<String> createBuy(Buy buy) async {
    final docBuy = Firestore.instance.collection('cart').doc();
                                                         ^^^
    buy.cID = docBuy.cID;
    await docBuy.set(buy.toJson());

    return docBuy.cID;
  }

  static Stream<List<Buy>> readBuyingList() => Firestore.instance
      .collection('todo')
      .orderBy(BuyingField.createdTime, descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .transform(Utils.transformer(Buy.fromJson));
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  static Future updateBuyingList(Buy buy) async {
    final docTodo = Firestore.instance.collection('cart').doc(buy.cID);
                                                          ^^^

    await docTodo.update(buy.toJson());
  }

  static Future deletedBuyingList(Buy buy) async {
    final docTodo = Firestore.instance.collection('cart').doc(buy.cID);
                                                          ^^^
    await docTodo.delete();
  }
}
```

> The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.

The above error appears in the code below (2)

(2). Utils.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Utils {
  static void showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String text) =>
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(text)));

  static DateTime toDateTime(Timestamp value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return null!;
    }
    return value.toDate();
  }

  static dynamic fromDateTimeToJson(DateTime date) {
    if (date == null) return null;

    return date.toUtc();
  }

  static StreamTransformer transformer<T>(
          T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json) fromJson) =>
      StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot, List<T>>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (QuerySnapshot data, EventSink<List<T>> sink) {
          final snaps = data.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
                             ^^^^
          final objects = snaps.map((json) => fromJson(json)).toList();
          sink.add(objects);
        },
      );
}
```

Comment: can you upgrade your `cloud_firestore`, then it will be `FirebaseFirestore.instance`

Comment: yes, this error occurs due to the version problem, because cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2 is required for other functionality for my app. How can I change from FirebaseFirestore.instance to Firestore.instance?